# iOS address bar fixed at top of viewport error

Tags: jquery, html, css, ios

first post here after trying to google the hell out of this thing. This issue is when viewing on the iPhone only.

Expected behavior: if you go to http://bbc.co.uk (or almost any website for that matter) on an iPhone and scroll down the page the address bar is gradually hidden until it is not visible.

What I am getting: The address bar is a fixed element at the top of the page similar to a regular desktop web browser.

Here is what I have (just a test page)

http://americansuccessnetwork.com/DEV/StackOverflow

I don't think it is anything in the jQuery because it still happens when I remove all javascript.

## edit SOLVED

I ended up fixing it by deleting some lines of CSS

```
html,body {    
 overflow:auto;
}
#explainer {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Apparently iOS Safari hates overflow.

This is why I never post things to stackoverflow... (it always ends up being something super simple)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problematic line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

You need to remove the `height` declaration.

Comment: Also: my problem is sort of complicated by the fact that I figured out I need the height set in order for my code to work. I have code that detects the browser's viewport height and sets the main div to that height if the browser is within a certain range (ie. mobile devices). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: On the `/DEV/` page, you have semicolons instead of commas: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">` .  That may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call  window.scrollTo(0, 0); once the page has finished loading. The BBC's website is calling when the page has been scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: I appreciate the response but that is not correct. They are not calling any scrollTo functions, they just leave the address bar to its native behavior.

Comment: OK well i maybe be incorrect about about how the BBC is doing it but doing scroll to oonce the site is loaded will that the desired effect. I know because I used it on this site http://www.welcometorecall.com/game/elevatorescape/ also you can add these two meta tags to your source. These will allow you to have more app like experience (removes bottom bar) if you chose to save the website to your homescreen and launch from there. 
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />